# req.body undefined when trying to parse it twice (see the code)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, body-parser

I'm building a nodemailer route handler using express in a MERN stack based application. I parsed the incoming request (these are form values that user inputs) into the route handler that sends email but at the same time I want to save the values in database as well for which I'm using mongoose.

here is the route handler:

```
const nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const multer = require ('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin');
const requireCredits = require('../middlewares/requireCredits');

const Project = mongoose.model('projects');

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(keys.gmailerClientID, keys.gmailerClientSecret, keys.gmailerRedirectURI);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
    refresh_token: keys.gmailerRefreshToken
});

var to;
var subject;
var path;

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './images')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname)
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: Storage
}).single('image');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/api/sendemail', requireLogin, requireCredits, async (req, res) => {

    const project = new Project({
      projectTitle: req.body.projectTitle, // form values are not parsing here (undefined)
      serviceSelect: req.body.serviceSelect,
      projectOwner: req.body.projectOwner,
      status: "Pending",
      slack: "Slack invite link",
      assets: "Cloud Storage asset link",
      _user: req.user.id,
      dateSent: Date.now()
    });

    upload(req, res, async function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.end("Something went wrong");
        }
        else{
          console.log(req.body.projectTitle);
            const output = `
                <ul>
                    <li>${req.body.serviceSelect}</li> //form values are parsed successfully
                    <li>${req.body.projectOwner}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.projectTitle}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.descriptionBox}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.teamSelector}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.deliverySpeed}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.deadline}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.timedl}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.timezone}</li>
                </ul>
            `;
            var to = "mail@outlook.com"
            var subject = req.body.projectTitle;
          try {
              var path = req.file.path;
          }

          finally{


            const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()

            var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'gmail',
                auth: {
                    type: 'OAuth2',
                    user: 'mail@gmail.com',
                    clientId: keys.gmailerClientID,
                    clientSecret: keys.gmailerClientSecret,
                    refreshToken: keys.gmailerRefreshToken,
                    accessToken: accessToken
                }
            })

            var mailOptions = {
                from: 'mail@gmail.com',
                to: to,
                subject: subject,
                html: output,
                attachments: [{
                    path: path
                }]
            }

            await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Email sent" + info.response)

                    fs.unlink(path, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            return res.end(err)
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("deleted")
                            return res.redirect('/result.html')
                        }
                    })

                }
            })
          }
        }
    });
    try{
      await project.save();
      req.user.mailCredits -= 1;
      const user = await req.user.save();

      res.send(user);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(422).send(err);
    }
});
};
```

The problem is that the main route handler has req.body empty or undefined whereas the multer upload variable successfully parses the value which eventually successfully sends the mail too but I want to save some of the values to my database which has been doing by creating a `project` instance which is where the form values are required but are undefined.
Any help to parse the value to the `/api/sendemail` route's `req` will solve my issue or please tell any other solutions too. Thank you.

Comment: What do you see when you log `req` object?

Comment: Undefined when I console.log it outside ``upload()``

Answer (score 0):

Insert the database save function inside the success response of the `transporter.sendMail()` function.

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin');
const requireCredits = require('../middlewares/requireCredits');

const Project = mongoose.model('projects');

const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(keys.gmailerClientID, keys.gmailerClientSecret, keys.gmailerRedirectURI);
oAuth2Client.setCredentials({
  refresh_token: keys.gmailerRefreshToken
});

var to;
var subject;
var path;

var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './images')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname)
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: Storage
}).single('image');

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post('/api/sendemail', requireLogin, requireCredits, async(req, res) => {

    upload(req, res, async function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.end("Something went wrong");
      } else {
        console.log(req.body.projectTitle);

        const output = `
                <ul>
                    <li>${req.body.serviceSelect}</li> //form values are parsed successfully
                    <li>${req.body.projectOwner}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.projectTitle}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.descriptionBox}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.teamSelector}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.deliverySpeed}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.deadline}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.timedl}</li>
                    <li>${req.body.timezone}</li>
                </ul>
            `;
        var to = "mail@outlook.com"
        var subject = req.body.projectTitle;
        try {
          var path = req.file.path;
        } finally {


          const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken()

          var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'gmail',
            auth: {
              type: 'OAuth2',
              user: 'mail@gmail.com',
              clientId: keys.gmailerClientID,
              clientSecret: keys.gmailerClientSecret,
              refreshToken: keys.gmailerRefreshToken,
              accessToken: accessToken
            }
          })

          var mailOptions = {
            from: 'mail@gmail.com',
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            html: output,
            attachments: [{
              path: path
            }]
          }

          await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err)
            } else {
              console.log("Email sent" + info.response)

              const project = new Project({
                projectTitle: req.body.projectTitle,
                serviceSelect: req.body.serviceSelect,
                projectOwner: req.body.projectOwner,
                status: "Pending",
                slack: "Slack invite link",
                assets: "Cloud Storage asset link",
                _user: req.user.id,
                dateSent: Date.now()
              });

              try {
                await project.save();
                req.user.mailCredits -= 1;
                await req.user.save();
              } catch (err) {
                res.status(422).send(err);
              }

              fs.unlink(path, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.end(err)
                } else {
                  console.log("deleted")
                  return res.redirect('/result.html')
                }
              })

            }
          })
        }
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: the value in the database can only be saved after a user successfully sends the mail because I have to deduct one from the ``mailCredits``

Comment: Edited the answer so that the database save() function is called after the email is sent.

Comment: the issue was resolved thank you for your help